# Masonry gallery with height fixed and width can be varied as per image size

Tags: css, reactjs

Masonry gallery with height fixed and width can be vary as per image size radio:
Actually what I need as this URL: https://www.imagesbazaar.com/search/Marriage?displayKeyword=544647474a4d44&br=1

They use:

```html
<div class="infinite-scroll-component " style="height: auto; overflow: auto;">
  <div class="custom-gallery">
    <div class="imageItem-Horizontal pie-menu-main-div">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://d3nn873nee648n.cloudfront.net/900x600/14201/120-SM520435.jpg" alt="SM520435" loading="lazy">
    </div>
    <div class="imageItem-Vertical pie-menu-main-div">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://d3nn873nee648n.cloudfront.net/900x600/17171/220-SM751807.jpg" alt="SM751807" loading="lazy">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is their code structure and I need to know how they manage the view.
if anyone can help me then that would be great.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal images have `900*600px` intrinsic size. And vertical images have `600*900x` intrinsic sizes. They have aspect ration 3:2 and 2:3 respectively. Images try to maintain the aspect ratio if you change the width then the height is automatically adjusted.

Playing on above aspect, same height has been ensured using `flex-grow` so if vertical images grows 1x then horizontal images grow 2.249 (150/66.667) times.

Optimal sizes have been ensured using relative `flex-basis`. The image wrapper divs try to maintain these sizes. Due to `flex-wrap: wrap` it works perfectly. If you reduce the browser width to minimum, when there is no scope for wrapping, then images start to become very tiny.

Apart from vertical and horizontal they have classes for more shapes:

```css
.custom-gallery .imageItem-Vertical {
  flex-grow: 66.667;
  flex-basis: 192px;
}

.custom-gallery .imageItem-Horizontal {
  flex-grow: 150;
  flex-basis: 432px;
}

.custom-gallery .imageItem-square {
  flex-grow: 100.5;
  flex-basis: 287.5px;
}
.custom-gallery .imageItem-HorizontalContributor {
  flex-grow: 150;
  flex-basis: 300px;
}
.custom-gallery .imageItem-VerticalContributor {
  flex-grow: 66.667;
  flex-basis: 133px;
}
```

Here is the minimal reproducible:

```css
.custom-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  line-height: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.imageItem-Horizontal {
  flex-grow: 2.249;
  flex-basis: 216px;
  margin: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.imageItem-Vertical {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 96px;
  margin: 3px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="infinite-scroll-component " style="height: auto; overflow: auto;">
  <div class="custom-gallery">
    <div class="imageItem-Horizontal pie-menu-main-div">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://d3nn873nee648n.cloudfront.net/900x600/14201/120-SM520435.jpg" alt="SM520435" loading="lazy">
    </div>
    <div class="imageItem-Vertical pie-menu-main-div">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://d3nn873nee648n.cloudfront.net/900x600/17171/220-SM751807.jpg" alt="SM751807" loading="lazy">
    </div>
    <div class="imageItem-Vertical pie-menu-main-div">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://d3nn873nee648n.cloudfront.net/900x600/17171/220-SM751807.jpg" alt="SM751807" loading="lazy">
    </div>
    <div class="imageItem-Vertical pie-menu-main-div">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://d3nn873nee648n.cloudfront.net/900x600/17171/220-SM751807.jpg" alt="SM751807" loading="lazy">
    </div>
    <div class="imageItem-Horizontal pie-menu-main-div">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://d3nn873nee648n.cloudfront.net/900x600/14201/120-SM520435.jpg" alt="SM520435" loading="lazy">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Summary

In short this masonry implementation works because of `flex-wrap: wrap`, ensured equal heights, and proportional `flex-grow` values.